# Why I'm unable to install a package with apt

Tags: debian, apt

On Debian 9 I want to install the package `libicu57` ([repository](https://packages.debian.org/testing/libicu57)), but for some reason I can't:

```
$ sudo apt install libicu57
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libicu57 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libicu57' has no installation candidate
```

In my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is this (beside others):

```
deb http://ftp.cvut.cz/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Testing is Debian 10 and frequent hiccups is the reason many people keeps on stable for production vms

Comment: Do you need the _testing_ version? It's also available in _stable_: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libicu57

Comment: testing is **not** Debian 9, it's 10, which doesn't contain `libicu57`, because it was replaced by `libicu60` and `libicu63`.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/buster/libicu57 Buster is Testing right?

Comment: @Michael look at the architectures for which that package is available (at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/issue`.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue at Hand

You wish to install `libicu57` from [the testing repo](https://packages.debian.org/testing/libicu57). However, if you are using `x86` or `amd64` you cannot install this package as it is only available in testing for `armel` `mips` and `mipsel`.

You have in your `sources.list` an entry for Debian Testing (Buster or 10). You report that you are using Debian 9 (Stretch or Stable). You have created [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). You need to configure your `sources.list` properly  remove this entry and rollback or remove any packages you have installed from the testing repo to correct this.

After you have done this, if it is the ARM variant of `libicu57` that you require you can look into cross compiling solutions or better yet virtualization.

#### Fix sources.list

First step is to verify that your repositories to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` are [good](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list). I would recommend you use `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` where each repository is it's own file, but you can do this in just one file.

```
#stable.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

#updates.list
deb http://deb.debian.org stable-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org stable-updates main contrib non-free 

#security.list 
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main contrib non-free
```

Your sources.list should look something like this. You can change the exact http address to match your desired mirror. If you must absolutely have a testing repo, add the entry in a similar manner as above and use [apt preferences](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) to maintain some level of sanity. Apt-pinning should be used sparingly as it can lead to the creation of FrankenDebian.

#### Install software

Now all that is left is installing your package, which can be done with this command:

```
 apt-get install libicu57
```

or

```
apt-get install -t stable libicu57 **or** apt-get install libicu57/stable
```

You can also choose to  install the package you desire from source or download it and its dependencies from the Debian Packages site and install them with `dpkg -i [packageName].deb`

This should install `libicu57`. Please comment if there is another error and we con look further into solutions. The next part is going to cover if you absolutely require the ARM or MIPS versions of software you can look into cross-compiling, or creating a virtual environment with the appropriate instruction set to safely use this version of the library.

[Here is the Debian Wiki entry on Multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) and [here is the Wiki for cross-compiling](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossCompiling). You can follow these steps to make the appropriate configuration changes to `dpkg` and what not to cross-compile.

**However you cannot have multiple versions of the same software installed!**

So if the ARM version requires dependencies and libraries that you already have a version of in `x86` or `amd64` then you cannot do this. The alternative is to create a virtual machine of Debian for ARM using the virtualization solution of your choice that uses the correct instruction set.

[KVM](https://wiki.debian.org/KVM) is a good choice but you can use whatever solution best fits your use case.

## Conclusion

Please [read over this in its entirety](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). In fact, please make sure you read over all the links I have provided thoroughly before running any commands. If you have any questions or concerns about this post, do not hesitate to ask me. If there are any corrections or misconceptions in this answer please inform me. I can update the post as necessary.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Installing `libicu57` from testing isn’t going to work, it’s not available there.

Comment: @StephenKitt, holy moly I did not pay attention. Let me correct that. Is is even possible to create a FrankenDebian of different instruction sets?

Comment: You can’t create a FrankenMultiArchDebian ;-) because all arches have to match up — so you can create a multi-arch FrankenDebian, but you can’t install packages with different versions for different architectures. However I don’t think that’s the problem here; I think the OP removed all stable repositories from the available sources, so your answer is mostly on track.

Comment: @StephenKitt I will clean it up. Thanks for the additional context.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem relates to some certain repositories then try to check you apt configuration in: /etc/apt/preferences.d/

It can have pinning files which not allow to upgrade these specific packages.

it can take place in docker images when changes in package version may brake things...

I hope this can help.